# How to attach file to mail using SSMTP ONLY!

Tags: ssmtp

I have this `bash` script that prepares and sends an email using SSMTP. The line that sends the message looks like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin/ssmtp -vvvv $recipients < $mail_file
```

$recipients: the recipient list
$mail_file: the mail file

How would I attach a "/var/logs/foo.log to this mail?
NB: An SSMTP-only solution is needed.

Comment: If you can't change the script, replace `/usr/local/sbin/ssmtp` with a link to a proper MIME-aware mailer.

Comment: I love the simplicity of SSMTP and I guess I have found an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Well... It turned out that this works just fine:

```
cat $mail_file | (cat - && uuencode /var/log/foo.log foo.log) | /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp -vvvv $recipients
```

Comment: Uuencode is so obsolete it's unimaginable. Use MIME and have it work properly.